# Button inside a Widget ListView does not trigger Broadcast

Tags: android, android-listview, android-widget, android-pendingintent, android-appwidget

My Widget is just a single ListView with an number of elements. Those should be clickable through the ListView and since all elements have two buttons, those should be clickable, too. The desired action on an button click is a broadcast, while a list element click should open an activity (which works).

The receiver is registered in the Manifest and has a corresponding intent-filter.

in `RemoteViewsFactory.getViewAt(int position)` this is done to add a PendingIntent:

```
private void registerButtonListener(RemoteViews remoteView, int id, int zoneId) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(WidgetTemperatureReceiver.ACTION);
    intent.putExtra("id", zoneId);
    intent.putExtra("up", id == R.id.buttonTempUp);
    intent.setClassName(WidgetTemperatureReceiver.class.getPackage().getName(), WidgetTemperatureReceiver.class.getName());
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(id, pending);

}
```

However nothing is received. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your package name or your class name is not being passed in properly.

Instead of this:

```
intent.setClassName(WidgetTemperatureReceiver.class.getPackage().getName(),
                    WidgetTemperatureReceiver.class.getName());
```

Use this:

```
intent.setClass(context, WidgetTemperatureReceiver.class);
```

where `context` is a reference to your `Activity` or `Service` or whatever component you are executing this method in.